# bool performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, boolean

Is there any performance difference in situations when `bool` is initialized with a value different from `0` and `1`?

I have read in [Optimizing C++ by Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) that:

> Boolean variables are overdetermined in the sense that all operators that have Boolean
>   variables as input check if the inputs have any other value than 0 or 1, but operators that
>   have Booleans as output can produce no other value than 0 or 1. This makes operations
>   with Boolean variables as input less efficient than necessary.

Can anybody explain what does it mean?

Comment: The book you've linked gives detailed examples and explains further just below that quote. If your question is "Should I never use bool again?", then the answer would be "No"!

Comment: *"all operators that have Boolean variables as input check if the inputs have any other value than 0 or 1"* That is not correct. The other text *"Boolean variables are stored as 8-bit integers with the value 0 for false and 1 for true."* is also not quite correct, the bits that make up `true` and `false` are not specified by the standard and compiler specific. You should consider ignoring everything in that PDF and read something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @nwp I thought `false` was specified as `0` and all other numbers are `true`.

Comment: @NathanOliver That only applies to integers, not to `bool`s. Possibly also applies to pointers, except that `nullptr` isn't necessarily all bits being `0`.

Comment: @nwp Note that AF's book is not about C++ in general, it is about specific implementations on specific platforms, as advertised at the beginning. Did you check what g++/clang++/sunCC (I only tested those 3) generate for `bool a,b,c;void fun(){c=a&&b;}` on x86_64-linux? Maybe that's a common bug in those compilers, but bugs can be relevant information. On the other hand, I agree that the statements in the book are too strong and the bool situation should not be presented as being so absolutely, unfixably broken.

Comment: @MarcGlisse No I missed that. It is undefined behavior which is even worse. Would recommend deleting immediately.